# Audio file from AWS s3 is not playing when accessed from my website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, audio

I'm setting up an audio file on my client's website and the audio is stored at aws s3 , a bucket policy is set up that allows only the users that are members of the site to open the audio files, pdfs etc. The problem is that bucket policy is working fine for the pdfs but it's not letting the audio files to play, when I remove all the blocks from the bucket and make it public then audio files work.

Does anyone know how I can sort this ?

Comment: Can you share the bucket policy?

Comment: Hi @Pacifist
Thank you for responding to this , here is the bucket policy but I had to change the name of the site and bucket due to client privacy

Comment: {
    
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
    
 "Id": "http referer policy example",
    
 "Statement":[
       
  {
           
   "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com",
            
 "Effect": "Allow",
           
 "Principal": {             
   "AWS": "*"
 },"Action": "s3:GetObject",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
   "Condition": { "StringLike": {
                        "aws:Referer": [
                          "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "https://example.com/*"
                    ]}}}]}

Answer (score -1):

This is an update regarding the above
I figured out the solution myself.
if someone else is facing the same issue then please add the url of the s3 file 
"https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/bucketname/* "
in the aws referer field:  "example.com*", "example.com*" "https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/bucketname/* "

```
replace bucketname with your bucket name.
```